# Tor Hidden service directories DHT topology

Tags: onion-services

what is the topology of the DHT used by Tor's hidden services ?

and while i understand 6 nodes will be responsible for a single HS, how many nodes would a client need to visit before finding the responsible HSDIR's

Thanks